# What is the best practice for repository?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

In my repositories, I have methods with too many arguments (for use in where) :

**Example :**

```
class ProchaineOperationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
        public function getProchaineOperation(
            $id = null, // Search by ID
            \DateTime $dateMax = null, // Search by DateMax
            \DateTime $dateMin = null, // Search by DateMin
            $title = null // Search by title
        )
```

In my controllers, I have differents action ... for get with **ID**, for get with **ID and DateMin**, for get **ID and Title**, ...

My method is too illegible because too many arguments ... and it would be difficult to create many methods because they are almost identical ...

What is the best practice ?

Comment: Your first best practice might be to respond to your questions.  This is the third question you have posted in 5 hours.  The other two have comments and answers but no responses from you.  And it looks like you have asked 50 questions and only accepted an answer to one?  Yikes.  Drive by posters should not expect much help.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main concerns in your question

> 1. You have too many arguments in your repository method which will be used in 'where' condition of the eventual query. You want to organize them in a better way
> 2. The repository method should be callable from the controller in a meaningful way because of possible complexity of arguments passed

I suggest you to write a Repository method like:

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Repository;

/**
 * ProchaineOperationRepository
 *
 */
class ProchaineOperationRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function search($filters, $sortBy = "id", $orderBy = "DESC")
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("po");

        foreach ($filters as $key => $value){
            $qb->andWhere("po.$key='$value'");
        }

        $qb->addOrderBy("po.$sortBy", $orderBy);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

The `$filters` variable here is an array which is supposed to hold the filters you are going to use in 'where' condition. `$sortBy` and `$orderBy` should also be useful to get the result in properly sequenced way

Now, you can call the repository method from your controller like:

```
class ProchaineOperationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/getById/{id}")
     */
    public function getByIdAction($id)
    {
        $filters = ['id' => $id];

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:ProchaineOperation")->search($filters);
        //process $result
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/getByTitle/{title}")
     */
    public function getByTitleAction($title)
    {
        $filters = ['title' => $title];
        $sortBy = 'title';

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:ProchaineOperation")->search($filters, $sortBy);
        //process $result

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/getByIdAndDateMin/{id}/{dateMin}")
     */
    public function getByIdAndDateMinAction($id, $dateMin)
    {
        $filters = ['id' => $id, 'dateMin' => $dateMin];
        $sortBy = "dateMin";
        $orderBy = "ASC";

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:ProchaineOperation")->search($filters, $sortBy, $orderBy);
        //process $result
    }

}
```

Note that you are calling the same repository method for all controller actions with minor changes according to your parameters. Also note that `$sortBy` and `$orderBy` are optionally passed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is only to query with an `AND` operator between each properties, the best way could be to use the method proposed by doctrine for that : `findBy()` cf : [this part of the doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

for instance :

```
$results = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:ProchaineOperation')
             ->findBy(array('dateMax' => $myDate, 'title' => 'Hello world');
```

EDIT : after comment

Then use the same way as Doctrine do : Pass only an array with id, dateMax... as keys if these are set. This should be solve the method signature problem which gives you so much trouble. :)

Comment: My code is much more complicated in reality ... and I use RSM and custom Queries :)